# Error by parsing Console.Readline() to int –

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, loops

I have a bit code of console application whose job is to get numbers from the user and add them to the array. But the problem is that I don't know how many numbers the user is going to input. So I decided to add some sort of stop key. For example, if there are enough numbers user can press "N" and continue to another part of code. So my first problem is how to make this code to not give unhandled format exception when any key is pressed.

```
int[] arrayInt = new int[100];

for (int i = 0; i < arrayInt.Length; i++)
{

    arrayInt[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (arrayInt[i] == Convert.ToChar (ConsoleKey.N))
    {
        //for example
        Console.WriteLine("You pressed n");

    }
```

Comment: `int.TryParse()`?

Comment: Or `var item = Console.ReadLine(); if (item == Console.Key.N) { break; ) else { int.TryParse(item, arrayInt[I]); }`.

Comment: You should edit your question header to something like this: Error by parsing Console.Readline() to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only a number or a letter, then you should use `Console.ReadKey` instead of `Console.ReadLine`.

You can use the following code, to get what you want.

```
    int[] arrayInt = new int[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayInt.Length; i++)
    {

        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        if(input.Equals("n")){
             //for example
            Console.WriteLine("You pressed n");
        }else{

            if(int.TryParse(input, out arrayInt[i])){
                Console.WriteLine("It's a number");
            }else{
                Console.WriteLine("No number and no n!");   
            }
        }
    }
```

You uses `ConsoleKey.N`, to check the "n". But with this, the user have to input "N". "n" doesn't work. If you want it not case sensetive, than you can change this line from my code:

```
if(input.Equals("n")){
```

to

```
if(input.ToLower().Equals("n")){
```